# Sorting out counts less than 10 before plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I got hospitalizations with patients that have certain diseases. Each of those hospitalizations has a certain release code when they get out of the hospital. I now have to plot the number of each release code in a bar chart. We just want to sort out numbers < 10 before plotting so it doesn't get too overloaded.

I recently started using R and am relatively new to it. Learned a lot of things already and every day something new. I really like to put those ggplot-Statements in 1 line without creating new variables for it.
So I know I could just do this by make a `plot <- count(cases, dismissCode, disease)` and just plot this. What I would like to do is just sorting out counts less than 10 on the x-axis in my ggplot-Statement.

Here is some code to reproduce it:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

komorbList <- c("komorb", "no komorb")
dismissesList <- c("No", "Un", "Co", "Unco", "Le", "Im", "Om", "Lo", "We", "Ha", "Si", "Lp", "Ng", "Hf")

dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(1:200),
  komorb = "na",
  dimiss = "na"
)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[ID == i, komorb := sample(komorbList, size=1, replace = TRUE)]
}

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[ID == i, dismiss := sample(dismissesList, size=1, replace = TRUE)]
}

count(dt, dismiss, komorb)

dt %>% ggplot(aes(dismiss, fill=stat(count))) + geom_bar(aes(y = stat(count)))
```

This should create at least a data.table with some necessary content and a bar-plot of it how I intend to do.

So again. Is there a way to filter out counts less than 10 within the aesthetics or something without making a count() statement beforehand?
Sorry if its a simple question or something. Just didn't really find anything yet.

Comment: Please add all necessary library calls to your code. Example: `library(data.table)`

Comment: Sorry sindri_baldur just inserted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rather prepare the data as much as possible before you feed it to `ggplot()` instead of modifying it in there: Here is a way to prepare and filter your data with `data.table` before you feed it to `ggplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
dt[, .(count = .N), by = dismiss][count >= 10] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dismiss, fill=count, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks sindri! Works like a charm. Can I ask you for an explanation or some reference where I can read about this .(count = .N)  within the brackets? I know about .N and all but this .() I didnt see yet.

Comment: @ChefKochNut This is syntax only used with `data.table`s. I think it is hard to seperate `.()` which is the same as `list()` from the rest of the data.table syntax. You might start here: https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html